# Hide <li> elements in list group for Umbraco grid editor

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, grid, umbraco

I made a custom grid editor for Umbraco that takes in 6 strings (1 header and 5 list items), to be displayed in a list group like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFMgL.png

But if the user doesn't enter values the remaining items, the li elements should not be displayed.

My controller is very simple, as it just contains the scopes for the various strings:

```
angular.module("umbraco").controller("my.custom.grideditorcontroller", function ($scope) {
    $scope.control.heading;
    $scope.control.punkt1;
    $scope.control.punkt2;
    $scope.control.punkt3;
    $scope.control.punkt4;
    $scope.control.punkt5;
});
```

The content editor is displayed 6 text boxes to enter the content in:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="control.heading" placeholder="Indtast overskrift">
<input type="text" ng-model="control.punkt1" placeholder="Indtast første punkt...">
<input type="text" ng-model="control.punkt2" placeholder="Indtast andet punkt...">
<input type="text" ng-model="control.punkt3" placeholder="Indtast tredje punkt...">
<input type="text" ng-model="control.punkt4" placeholder="Indtast fjerde punkt...">
<input type="text" ng-model="control.punkt5" placeholder="Indtast femte punkt...">
```

And this is what is rendered in the view:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<dynamic>
<div class="">
    <div class="list-group">
        <div class="list-group-item">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">@Model.heading</h4>
            <ul class="ul-with-bullets">
                <li>@Model.punkt1</li>
                <li>@Model.punkt2</li>
                <li>@Model.punkt3</li>
                <li>@Model.punkt4</li>
                <li>@Model.punkt5</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
```

How do I check whether the show the li element based on my scope values? I tried using "ng-if="@Model.punkt1 != null", but it still returns an empty li element for the values with no entered input.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your model is not null and contains an empty value. You can try the following, which will check whether the value is null, empty or undefined:

```
<ul class="ul-with-bullets">
    <li ng-if="@Model.punkt1">@Model.punkt1</li>
    <li ng-if="@Model.punkt2">@Model.punkt2</li>
    <li ng-if="@Model.punkt3">@Model.punkt3</li>
    <li ng-if="@Model.punkt4">@Model.punkt4</li>
    <li ng-if="@Model.punkt5">@Model.punkt5</li>
</ul>
```